# bash to print certain file names to text

Tags: bash, printing, if-statement

I have spent a lot of time the past few weeks and posting on here.  I finally think I am much closer with learning bash but I have one problem with my code I cannot for the life of me figure out why it will not run.  I can run each line in the terminal and it returns a result but for some reason when I point it to run, it will do nothing.  I get a a syntax error: word unexpected (expecting "do").

```
#!/bin/bash

image="/Home/Desktop/epubs/images"

for f in $(ls "$image"*.jpg); do
    fsize=$(stat --printf= '%s' "$f");
    if [ "$fsize" -eq "40318" ]; then
       echo "$(basename $f)" >> results.txt
    fi
done
```

What am I missing???

Comment: Your `ls` command is acting as a glorified echo - assuming it works at all, which it probably doesn't without a `/` between `"$image"` and `*.jpg`.  Just do `for f in "$image"/*.jpg; do`.  Also, you have an extra space between `--printf=` and `'%s'` that will break your `stat` command.

Comment: @sean explain what you mean please

Comment: @CuriousGeorge you've asked 5 other questions on StackOverflow and have never marked one of the responses as an answer.

Comment: @CuriousGeorge When you ask a question, if you get an answer that helps you, you should "Accept" that answer.  This gives the person who answered you reputation points, and other people more incentive to answer your questions in the future.

Comment: @MarkReed thanks I will go back and accept all answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your for loop appears to be missing a list of values to iterate over:

```
image="/Home/Desktop/epubs/images"
for f in $(ls "$image"*.jpg); do
```

Because `$image` does not end with a /, your `ls` command expands to

```
for f in $(ls /Home/Desktop/epubs/images*.jpg); do
```

which probably results in

```
for f in ; do
```

causing the syntax error. The simplest fix is

```
for f in $(ls "$image"/*.jpg); do
```

but you should take the advice in the other answers and skip `ls`:

```
for f in "$image"/*.jpg; do
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be in line endings. Make sure your script file has unix line endings, not the Windows ones.

Also, do not iterate over output of `ls`. Use globbing right in the shell:

```
for f in "$file"/*.jpg ; do
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do that.

```
#!/bin/bash -e

image="/Home/Desktop/epubs/images"

(cd "$image" 
 for f in *.jpg; do
   let fsize=$(stat -c %s "$f")
   if (( fsize == 40318 )); then
     echo "$f"
   fi
 done) >results.txt
```

The `-e` means the script will exit if anything goes wrong (can't cd into the directory, for instance).  Saves a lot of error checking when you're happy with that behavior.

The parentheses mean that the `cd` command is in a subshell; the surrounding script (including the redirection into `results.txt`) is still in whatever directory you started in.

Now that we're in the directory, we can just look for `*.jpg`, no directory prefix, and no need to call `basename` on anything.

Using `let` and `(( == ))` treats the size value as a number instead of a string, so we won't get tripped up by any wonkiness in the way `stat` chooses to format the value.

We just redirect the output the entire loop into the result file instead of appending every time through; it's more efficient.  If you have existing contents in `results.txt` that you want to keep, you can just change the `>` back to a `>>`, but leaving it around the whole loop is still more efficient than opening the file and appending to it on every iteration.

Comment: when I do cd Desktop/epubs I press enter.  Path is correct and I try sh test.sh on the script above.  I return three errors.  Two are :not found: debug.sh: and the other is debug.sh 6: debug.sh: Syntax error: word unexpected )expecting "do").  That message is displayed on my old script above, too.

Comment: `sh` and `bash` are two different shells (even if they're the same program).  This script has to be run with bash, not sh.

Comment: my apologies I am still new at this.  Are you referring to how the .sh file is ran in the terminal? As ./filename apposed to sh filename.sh?

Comment: you can make the file executable and then just do `./filename.sh` (assuming you have `#!/bin/bash` at the top of the file).  Or you can explicitly do `bash ./filename.sh`.  The important thing is to use `bash`, not `sh`.

Comment: ive ran everything as bash ./filename.sh, sh filename.sh, double clicked and executed in terminal.  None of the suggested code would work.  I run the exact code you have above with bash ./filename.sh and i receive errors on line 6.  "Syntax error near unexpected token '$'do\r'' and ' for f in *.jpg; do

Comment: Yeah, sounds like line-ending problems.  You need to get rid of the carriage returns in the script.  Newlines only.